# How convert a string representation of date array to array JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to convert a string representation of array to JS array for looping purpose
the string is single quoted

in My js

```
var length1 = $('.length').text();  //['2018-9-24', '2018-9-26', '2018-9-25']
console.log(length1.length) // 39 as output i need it as 3
```

to loop through each date

Any help would be appreciated

I tried

```
var myArray=json.parse(length1) // but its not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace single quotes with double and then parse it:

```js
var str = "['2018-9-24', '2018-9-26', '2018-9-25']";

console.log(JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"')));
```

Comment: hi am facing an issue missing parentheses but is working fine in the console when i put it in my js it's not working  all ))); this become green instead of white or ending parentheses

Comment: Thank You for Yor Effort and answer brother. its working fine in the Console When i add the same code to script its shows some Error

Comment: @abhikrishnan You are welcome. May be that error is because of some other part of your code. I won't be here for a while. You may ask a new question with the relevant error and necessary code to reproduce the error. Hopefully you will get an answer.

Comment: its ok brother I had done that in the below way which i posted as an answer if someone get same error means it will helpfull to them so. I posted it as an answer below. Thank YOu Verymuch for your Effort and Valuable Time. Thank YOu.

Answer (score 0):

I had done this in an another way

```
var objectstring = "['2018-9-24', '2018-9-26', '2018-9-25']";
var objectStringArray = (new Function("return [" + objectstring+ "];")());
```